# IllegalArgumentException when calling AudioSystem.getClip()

Tags: java, runtime-error, illegalargumentexception, java-17

I'm trying to play audio in a Tetris-style game I've made in Java, and I don't want to pull in any external dependencies to do this. When looking for ways to play audio in Java without external libraries, I found `AudioSystem.getClip()` which seemed to give me what I wanted. However, when I use this, an IllegalArgumentException is immediately thrown.

The error can be reproduced even with something minimal like this:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;

public class AudioTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {
        final Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    }
}
```

Running this gives me the following stacktrace:

```
/mnt/storage/Programs/Flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.openjdk17/x86_64/21.08/active/files/jvm/openjdk-17/bin/java -javaagent:/app/idea-IC/lib/idea_rt.jar=37847:/app/idea-IC/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /mnt/storage/Programming/audio-test/out/production/audio-test AudioTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface Clip supporting format PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian is supported.
    at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:425)
    at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getClip(AudioSystem.java:461)
    at AudioTest.main(AudioTest.java:7)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So what might I be doing wrong here? If I'm reading the documentation right, I shouldn't need to provide any argument to this method: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getClip()

It does say that this exception is thrown "if the system does not support at least one clip instance through any installed mixer", but I don't particularly understand what that means. How should I go about resolving this?

For what it's worth, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community with OpenJDK 17 built by Flathub on Fedora (Linux) 34 with PipeWire as my audio system (support for PulseAudio enabled).

Comment: The error message is complaining about an unsupported clip format, and the page you linked to says _"If the system property javax.sound.sampled.Clip is defined or it is defined in the file "sound.properties", it is used to retrieve the default clip"_. So have you tried modifying either of those?

Comment: If you print out `Arrays.toString(AudioSystem.getMixerInfo())`, what do you see?

Comment: @VGR It's an empty array. (i.e. `[]`)

Comment: It appears you need ALSA support, according to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/troubleshoot/java-sound.html.

Comment: Okay, so, the issue was that I'm running IntelliJ in a Flatpak, and by default this does not let IntelliJ (and as such any applications spawned by it) use ALSA to play back music directly. Not sure how this question should be answered exactly.

Answer (score 0):

A not particularly great way to get this to work is to use `AudioSystem.getClip(null);`. I just migrated one of my projects to Linux and I had to refactor my code to include this methodology for the audio. It's not the greatest fix but it's the best one I could find.

If you'd like a more constructive solution you could refactor your code like this

```
File soundFile = new File("/full/path/to/sound.wav");
AudioInputStream soundIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
AudioFormat format = soundIn.getFormat();
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clip.open(soundIn);
clip.start();
```

The magic here is with `soundIn.getFormat()`.

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: From what I've read, audio is fairly buggy for Linux (PulseAudio being the default audio mixer for Linux). This is one of the solutions I know of, although I'm not sure of the reasoning behind it working. I apologize for not being able to elaborate. I'm glad it seemed to work for you, if you could upvote I would appreciate it :)

Comment: Edited in another way you might be able to refactor your code. I think this is more what you may be looking for?